# Probability that a person can get from W to T?

Tags: probability

What is the probability that a person can get from city **W** to city **T** as shown in the picture below? The probabilities shown below are the probabilities that the roads are passable. (**C** and **D** are two other cities).
[image]

I tried:

So I see that there are 4 possible paths WCT (A), WDT (B), WCDT (C), and WDCT (D).

Let **S** denote all paths from **W** to **T**. Then,

$P(S) = P(A \ \cup \ B \ \cup \ C \ \cup \ D )\\$

I'm not sure if I set it up right.

EDIT: I found from the answer key that the correct answer is 0.958 but I'm still not sure how to get to that.

Comment: What about loops?

Comment: Are the numbers probabilities that the paths are open?  *You should say that*.  Once you do, can you compute the chance that WCT is open?  I would find it easier to compute the chance that you can't get from W to T.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum of probabilities of paths from a point be 1?

Comment: @quasi:  No, D is most likely, but the probability is enhanced by the chance that A is available when D is not.

Comment: I just found the answer in the answer key which is 0.958. But I still don't know how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: To the OP: Are you stating the problem exactly as in the source? What is the source? Is it a book? If so, which one (author, title), and what problem (page number, problem number)?

Comment: @quasi Yes I am.

Comment: Surely the problem used some _words_ to define what those numbers represent. No?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the probabilities are the probabilities that the roads are passable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should consider two cases: $CD$ is passable and $CD$ is blocked.

(1) When $CD$ is passable:
The only cases we can't pass are $WC,WD$ are both blocked and $CT,DT$ are both blocked. However when we count the second blocked probability we need to assume the first is not blocked in order to avoid double counting.

So we have the probability $0.95(1- 0.2\cdot 0.1 - (1-0.2\cdot0.1)\cdot0.1\cdot0.2)=0.91238$

(2) When $CD$ is blocked:
We have only two paths. Logic similar to the first case.

$0.05(0.8\cdot0.9+(1-0.9\cdot0.8)\cdot 0.9\cdot0.8) = 0.4608$

Add both cases up, we have 0.95846

Comment: Note: the number on the RHS of the final expression should be $0.04608$, not $0.4608$.

Answer (score 2):

The question comes from the book **Introduction to Probability by Grinstead and Snell**. See pp 152/153 (question 32) in this PDF version found [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Eprob/prob/prob.pdf).

The OP is part of a three part question. It's useful to recap the first two questions.

**Q1:** What's the probability of going from W to T, where *p* and *q* are the probabilities that the roads are passable?

[image: Image for question 1]

In this case, it is simply **pq**.

**Q2:** What's the probability of going from W to T, where *p* and *q* are the probabilities that the roads are passable?

[image]

In this case, it is **1 - (1 - p)(1 - q)**. In other words, 1 minus the probability that both roads are closed.

**Q3:** What's the probability of going from W to T, given the probabilities shown that a given road is passable?

[image]

As pointed out in the accepted answer, we can approach this by considering two scenarios; when (a) CD is unpassable, and (b) CD is passable.

For (a) we have a set-up similar to Q2. In this case, the probability of going from W to T is:

1 - (1 - 0.8 x 0.9)(1 - 0.8 x 0.9) = 1 - (0.28)(0.28) = 0.9216

[image]

For (b), we consider the ways in which it is not possible to get from W to T: namely when either (i) WC and WD are both closed, or (ii) CT and DT are both closed.

[image]

For (i) we have:

(1 - 0.8) x (1 - 0.9) = 0.2 x 0.1 = 0.02.

For (ii) we have the same calculation, *except that it is conditional on WC/WD not being closed* (if they were closed, we've already accounted for it in (i).

- WC/WD not closed = 1 - (1 - 0.8)(1 - 0.9) = 1 - (0.2)(0.1) = 0.98
- CT/DT closed = (1 - 0.8) x (1 - 0.9) = 0.2 x 0.1 = 0.02.
- WC/WD not closed **and** CT/DT closed = 0.98 x 0.02 = 0.0196

So probability of getting from W to T is given by:

1 - (i + ii) = 1 - (0.02 + 0.0196) = 1 - 0.0396 = 0.9604

Putting it all together, we need to multiply our answers for (a) and (b) by the probability that CD is passable or not, and then add them together.

a) Scenario where CD is unpassable = 0.9216 * 0.05 = 0.04608

b) Scenario where CD is passable = 0.9604 * 0.95 = 0.91238

(a) + (b) = **0.95846**